# Review the route dynamically Symfony2

Tags: php, security, url, symfony, permissions

Hello I need get the route and review if the have access to this, reviewing on the database but a level really abstract and automatic. By now i am making that on this form:

```
$accesos = MenuQuery::create()
            ->useAccesoMenuQuery()
            ->usePerfilQuery()
            ->usePerfilUsuarioQuery()
            ->filterByUsuarioId($this->getUser()->getId())
            ->endUse()
            ->endUse()
            ->endUse()
            ->orderBy('menu.orden')
            ->groupBy('menu.id')
            ->find();
    $permiso = false;
    foreach ($accesos as $acceso) {
        if (($acceso->getDireccion() == $ruta) || ($permiso)) {
            $permiso = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $permiso;
}
```

I am using this php function for make that. But i need to make that on the firewalls of symfony2 or another form but abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form that I did it was using a Event Listener of Symfon2 Here I leave to yours my own code.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
class SoporteListener {

private $container;
private $acceso = 0;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $this->container->get('request');
    $routeName = $request->get('_route');
    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    if (($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_USUARIO')) && 
            ($routeName != 'done_login') &&
            ($routeName != 'done_logout')) {
        $usuario = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $permisos = MenuQuery::create()
                ->useAccesoMenuQuery()
                ->usePerfilQuery()
                ->usePerfilUsuarioQuery()
                ->filterByUsuarioId($usuario->getId())
                ->endUse()
                ->endUse()
                ->endUse()
                ->groupBy('menu.id')
                ->find();
        foreach ($permisos as $permiso) {
            if (($permiso->getDireccion() == $routeName)) {
                $this->acceso = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($this->acceso == 0) {
            $event->setResponse($this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('::error.html.twig', array('error' => 'Permiso denegado')));
        } else {
            return;    
        }
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One way, and if the routes are generic, set up ACL in the security.yml where you can specify that for example ^/admin/.* require ROLE_ADMIN.
If you have special roles, for example, ACCOUNT_ADMIN where it's depending on what is the selected account, then you need to write your own VOTER, where you can decide that at a specific point, is the rights are enough or not.